# LabelItemRenderer VS IconItemRenderer?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

As I am tuning performance of my adobe AIR app for mobile, I read at adobe docs:

> Subclass LabelItemRenderer or IconItemRenderer You can improve
>   performance by writing your item renderer in ActionScript and building
>   off of the highly-optimized Flex LabelItemRenderer or
>   IconItemRenderer. To implement your LabelItemRenderer or
>   IconItemRenderer subclass, you override the item renderer's data
>   setter and the createChildren , measure , drawBackground , and
>   layoutContents methods.

But there is no mention when to prefer `IconItemRenderer` over `LabelItemRenderer` or vice versa .. is there any informative answer on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use IconItemRenderer when you want to display an image as part of your renderer.   Use LabelItemRenderer when you just want to display text.

Comment: @simo It is trivial to create your own MXML Extension of a LabelItemRenderer and add an image of it; but that defeats the purpose of using an ActionScript-specific optimized renderer.  It is not trivial to extend LabelItemRenderer in ActionScript and add an image to it [it is not difficult; but I'd hardly call it trivial].

Comment: Agreed wholeheartedly with @Reboog711 here. There are a few tricks to properly adding a `DisplayObject` to a mobile `ItemRenderer`. It's not quite as easy as using MXML or calling `addChild`. For example, you **must** use `StyleableTextField` over `Label` and any `Image` or `BitmapImage` must be added to a container before being added to the renderer. @simo In your previous question, I suggested you read Reboog's article on mobile renderers. I still highly suggest doing that. https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/24/Building-a-Mobile-ItemRenderer-in-Flex